# Modify a Google Slides presentation while presenting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm afraid I already know the answer, but maybe someone else has found a way to do this.

I've been perusing the Slide Apps Script reference, and I'm excited about the possibilities. One thing I would like to do is alter a slide mid-presentation. Specifically, I would like to somehow indicate a link has been clicked.

If links in a presentation turned purple like web links I would settle for that, but I would like to use a trigger when a certain link is clicked or when a certain slide is shown. This trigger could run a script that alters the slide with the link appropriately to show the link has been clicked or even remove the link altogether.

I know the Slides API is behind the others, but Forms have installable triggers that can run `onFormSubmit` and Spreadsheets have triggers that run `onChange` and `onEdit`. I would love to see Slides have an onPresent trigger that ran a script that could detect slide changes with methods like `onSlideChange` that could report currentSlide. That way we could run scripts while the presentation is showing and take action based on current slides or links.

Aside from Slide specific triggers being added to the API, is there any way to modify slides during a presentation? Or at least show that a link has been clicked?

Comment: If you are in presentation mode this is not possible. If presenting using edit view (a lot of people present that way) then all the changes (using script or manually on another device) are live edited like in google docs or spreadsheet.

Comment: @RohanSharma hmm, thanks for the tip! That is something I hadn't considered. I might be able to work with that. Thanks.

Comment: It was disappointing that this is the first link for "Edit Google Slides while presenting" where I didn't have any intention to do scripting, but simply wanted to know if I could edit the slide being presented through a secondary screen or device and it would instantly update on the projector. It seems PowerPoint can do this (through the presenter view).